# Datetime column adding Current Timestamp even NULL is inserted

Tags: mysql

I have table login :

tbl: login

```
name          type        Allow Null

id          varchar(36)     Yes
coy_id      varchar(36)     Yes
client_id   varchar(36)     Yes
logindt     Datetime        Yes
logoutdt    Datetime        Yes
```

When I Insert:

```
INSERT INTO login (id, coy_id, client_id, logindt, logoutdt) 
VALUES ('7E6B6C24-20AF-439C-B3CD-26F6425881C9', '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111', '12341234-1234-1234-1234-123412341234', '2014-07-30 13:47:54.727', NULL);`
```

`logoutdt` adding current time stamp,instade of null Why? [image]

***update** :
 [image]

**Update 2** Update query working fine

`UPDATE login SET logoutdatetime= NULL  WHERE id ='7e6b6c24-20af-439c-b3cd-26f6425881c9';`

Comment: Please show the output of `show create table login`.

Answer (score 0):

Because of your table declaration.

You need to declare logoutdt and login dt to have DEFAULT NULL when you create the table, else it will put in CURRENT TIMESTAMP

Answer (score 0):

Try this query, By setting default value of column to null:

```
ALTER TABLE login MODIFY COLUMN logoutdatetime DATETIME DEFAULT NULL;
```

**Update:** check this [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/00780/1). Its working as you want.

Comment: well actually i didn't wanted to put my real table names :P

Answer (score 0):

> There is some problem with your table structure see SQLFiddle [**Here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/15063/1). It work fine for me why not working in your case. Please check proper table structure and modify required changes.

Comment: Hi, No i can not change the `Type`

Comment: I have no Idea, BTW there is no `Primary Key` in my table.